# DIY detection of plug connection

Tags: power, connector

I have a male type of plug with 4 exposed terminals that connects to a female plug of the same sort. 2 terminals are power, GND/VCC and two are data lines. With 4 exposed terminals, the chances are that a piece of metal or conductive material could easily short the VCC and GND.

To prevent this short I was going to put a MOSFET on the GND or VCC, and only enable those lines once a connection was detected.

The question is how to detect this connection? Assuming I can't measure it mechanically, only electrically. One method I was considering was to use similar to USB, and include pulldown resistors, on the data lines, and then apply a voltage and measure the corresponding voltage, however this still involves enabling the voltage line, when there's no guarantee there's not a short between the VCC and the GND. Is there a way to determine a valid connection or simply that there's not a short before hand?

Comment: Wouldn't a polyfuse or similar be a better idea?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen not in my mind, it's better to prevent an incident than fusing in case of it

Comment: You do know that a polyfuse is self-resetting?

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyUtlI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Without knowing how much current you are switching, this idea is diagrammatic - adjust resistor values to suit your needs and use a suitable switch element.

The principle is simple - if there is a short before connection, the Sense line will be at Gnd, if not it will be at Vcc/2. (Of course, once the switch closes Sense will be at Vcc, which may need protection of your sensing circuit.) Once the connection is made, Sense will drop to some lower value; this is how you detect the connection.

Comment: This works well, but ultimately needs another connector line just for the sense line, is this avoidable or just a sacrifice to be made to get the desired behaviour